# HTTP 400 on simple ASP.Net Core Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to create a simple "Hello world" ASP.Net Core 3.1 app, but trying to POST a form, I keep getting:

> This page isn’t working.  If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
>
> HTTP ERROR 400

Steps to reproduce:

1. MSVS2019 > New Project > ASP.Net Core Web Application, C#
2. DELETE the boilerplate, auto-generated code in Pages\*, substitute my own Index.cshtml and Index.cshtml.cs
3. Run program. I see my form.
4. Click "submit".  I get HTTP 400.

**Pages\Index.cshtml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace HelloUploads.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    { 
    
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model HelloUploads.Pages.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
}

<form method="post">
   <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

I'm sure the problem is simple.  I've tried many variations, and I've been banging my head for several hours.

Q: What am I doing wrong?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is probably anti-forgery tokens. Add @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers to the page

```
@page
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@model HelloUploads.Pages.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
}

<form method="post">
   <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

on the code behind add [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
   return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

Hope it works!

Comment: this totally fixed it for me, this was especially helpful because there was absolutely NO error messages of any kind as to what went wrong, I just stumbled on this post out of desperation and luck, but it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Q: What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

The code you provided has no problem, in the vast majority of possible scenarios, a 400 Bad Request is a `client-side` issue caused by *the submitted request to the server or a local caching issue*.

You can try the following solutions to solve your issue.

1. Check the Submitted URL
2. Clear Browser Cache
3. Clear Browser Cookies
4. File Upload Exceeds Server Limit
5. Clear DNS Cache
6. Deactivate Browser Extensions

More details, you can refer to [this](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/400-bad-request/#fix).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I believe you're absolutely correct - this particular "HTTP 400" is indeed probably a client-side issue.  Unfortunately, clearing browser cache/cookies deleting/rebuilding project binaries didn't help; DNS cache/file upload size aren't applicable.  I'll keep you posted what I find....